# How to display dynamic html content inside a table cell (as html page preview)?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have this weird request, please bear with me :)

I'm using javascript (AJAX) to call an API to get some data, and among these data i get html code of a complete page as preview, what i want to do is to display all these data along with the preview (interpreted ofcourse) in a table.

What i found so far, is that i can create iframe element and to write the html code into the document of the iframe, it's kind of working, but it's not very practical,  as i don't have so much control over the iframe, it's so tiny in the height and the user have to scroll to see the entire page.

What is typical for this situation is to use sort of image thumbnails, and display them on the table cell? but unfortunately the API only gives html code.

What i want to ask please is, do i have any other elegant solution other than the iframe, or the iframe is my only choice?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform some string manipulation and extract exactly the content you need from your ajax call response. Assuming your response looks like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div>  <!-- extract from this div -->
        the content you need
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

You need to extract from the `div` tag and append it to the tag you want to embed it to. You are dropping out the top html tags and the `body` tag *because you already have it in your page* otherwise you will need to use an `iframe`.